# MeteorJS, iron-router, filters, redirection, delay

Tags: meteor, delay, iron-router

```
Router._filters = {

  isLoggedOut: function (pause) {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      return this.redirect('home');
    } else {
      this.next();
    }
  },

  isLoggedIn: function (pause) {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      return this.redirect('dashboard');
    } else {
      this.next();
    }
  }

};

filters = Router._filters;

Router.onBeforeAction(filters.isLoggedOut, { except: [
  'home'
]});

Router.onBeforeAction(filters.isLoggedIn, { only: [
  'home'
]});
```

I'd like to make filter in iron-router which makes redirect to 'home' when user is not logged in and to 'dashboard' if user is logged in. Everything works, but in the first case dashboard is shown for a second and then redirect is done. How can I get rid of this delay?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom controller.

```
// Global Router configuration
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
    controller: BaseController
});
```

The code above says: "For all existing paths, use the `BaseController`"

Your BaseController should look like this

```
BaseController = RouteController.extend({
  action: function() {
    if(!Meteor.userId()) {
      // this.render('home');
      // this.go('home);
      this.redirect('home');
    }
    else {
      // this.render('dashboard');
      // this.go('dashboard');
      this.redirect('dashboard');
    }
  }
})
```

If you need more controll for each site,give your specific site a controller, which inherit from the BaseController. It should looks like this

```
// Global Router configuration
// Remove the controller property!
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('contact', {
        path: '/contact',
        controller: 'ContactController'
    })
});
```

Your ContactController should looks like this

```
ContactController = BaseController.extend({
    // Do something with this given route,
    // e.g., give it a name property or so
    name: 'contact',
    action: function() {

    }
})
```

For more information, check the Iron.Router guide.
https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-controllers

Comment: I've done this but still there is a delay:
  action: function () {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      this.redirect('home');
    } else {
      this.render();
    }
  }

Comment: what do you mean with "delay"? Is `dashboard` still displaying?

Comment: I mean that dashboard is displaying for a second and then home is displaying.

Comment: I don't know if it matters but I've set in Router.configure(); layoutTemplate: 'Layout' and probably only it is displaying.

Comment: Sure. http://pastebin.com/G0QbCGHr . This is a modified version, but still 'Layout' is displaying for a while.